# clonezilla moving to bigger harddrive

Tags: linux, partitioning, centos, clonezilla

I successfully cloned my hard drive from 250gb to 1Tb using -k1 on expert mode. 
but when I explore the folders, why is it still acting like a 250 gb hard drive. It is still showing that 180gb available as it was showing same when it was 250gb any idea what I am missing?

I am running centos linux

Answer (score 4):

Clonezilla copied the data from your original disk to the target disk exactly, including your partition table.  You now have to resize your partition.

You can either use something like gparted, or you can use fdisk if you're feeling lucky to expand the partition to take up the entire disk and then resize your filesystem with resize2fs or the like.

Comment: I love gparted for things like this.

Comment: I have Gparted installed
Clonezilla made LVM bigger, but I need help to make the size of /dev/mapper/VG0-var bigger
LVM is got the biggest space.But there is no partition called /dev/mapper/VG0-var
so how do I resize /dev/mapper/VG0-var
any ideas more than welcome. thanks

Comment: Ok, so you need to first increase the partition and do pvresize to make the PV the full disk size, then lvextend and resize each LV that you need to add space to.

This should do the trick...
lvextend -L +1G /dev/VG0/var ; resize2fs /dev/VG0/var

Answer (score 1):

GParted is a good partition program but it did not work in my case, since I had to deal with LVM file system.

By guidance of '**baumgart**' the lifesaver, I managed to resize /dev/VG0/var with the following three steps:

1. `pvresize --setphysicalvolumesize  700G /dev/sda1` (resize sda1 to 700Gigabytes)
2. `lvextend -L +500G /dev/VG0/var` (add 500Gigabytes top on existing)
3. `resize2fs /dev/VG0/var`

This is done after clonezilla expert mode -k1 is applied.

Answer (score 0):

Use a tool like [Parted Magic](http://partedmagic.com/) to resize the partition and take advantage of the full space.

Comment: I have Gparted installed
Clonezilla made LVM bigger, but I need help to make the size of /dev/mapper/VG0-var bigger
LVM is got the biggest space.But there is no partition called /dev/mapper/VG0-var
so how do I resize /dev/mapper/VG0-var
any ideas more than welcome. thanks